# create array for each same month in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have got an  response with number of **values** with same **month**.

If you can see the left one (TAR_HEF_01,TAR_HEF_02...)are the months and right one are the values for the same.

in this each month (lets say TAR_HEF_01) contain 4 values.

i have 6 months in a array.i have got monthIndexValue through loop like below.

```
hebrewMonthArray.forEach((monthValue, index) => {
let monthIndex = hebrewMonthArray.indexOf(hebrewMonthArray[index]);
      monthIndexValue =
        monthIndex < 9
          ? `TAR_HEF_0${monthIndex + 1}`
          : `TAR_HEF_${monthIndex + 1}`;
```

i have got value like below

```
Object.keys(allWorkDetails).forEach((work, index) => {
let value = allWorkDetails[work][monthIndexValue][0] || 0;
 }); 
});
```

**Here is the console of **monthIndexValue** and **value** **:---

```
TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_06 90
TAR_HEF_06 9
TAR_HEF_06 -200.8
TAR_HEF_06 214.9
```

i want to create one array for each month contain their values.

if i will put **console(monthIndexValue,arrayOfValue);**

the output should be:---

```
TAR_HEF_01 [0,0,0,0]
TAR_HEF_02 [0,0,0,0]
TAR_HEF_03 [0,0,0,0]
TAR_HEF_04 [0,0,0,0]
TAR_HEF_05 [0,0,0,0]
TAR_HEF_06 [90,9,-200.8,214.9]
```

How can i solve? Thanks...

Comment: those inputs are from JSON-formatted data?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like reading CSV format in JS, reading content line by line and split on spaces?

Comment: can you please share how this data is coming in the response? Is it an array or it is in the object and how do you want the result in array or object?

Comment: No..those are only numbers..

Comment: @Ashishgoodluckchuck Can you add the piece of code that is returning this response?

Comment: i have added some code for your reference.

Comment: can anyone please suggest how can i get this output?

Answer (score 2):

If the response is a multiline string like you showed in your question, let's put its content in the response var like this:

```
const response = `TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_01 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_02 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_03 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_04 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_05 0
TAR_HEF_06 90
TAR_HEF_06 9
TAR_HEF_06 -200.8
TAR_HEF_06 214.9`;

//now split the lines and put them in splitLines array
let splitLines = response.split(/\r?\n/);
let map = [];

//loop through each line    
splitLines.forEach( (o, i) => {
  //parse the string to isolate month and value
  let parsed = o.split(" ");
  let parsedMonth = parsed[0];
  let parsedValue = parsed[1];
  //se map still doesn't contain the key parsedMonth
  if( typeof map[parsedMonth] === 'undefined' ){
    //create a new empty array bound to the key parsedMonth in map
    map[parsedMonth] = [];
  }
  //add the new value to the array bound to the parsedMonth in map
  map[parsedMonth].push(parsedValue);  
});
```

At this point you have map with keys having values grouped by month.